# anchor tag with html decode asp.net function

Tags: dwt

I am using below line of code in my DWT.

```
<h2>
    <a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">
        <%=Html.ServerDecode("@@Component.Fields.Name@@")%>
    </a>
</h2>
```

When I visit website it shows me string <%=Html.ServerDecode("@@Component.Fields.Name@@")%> as it is because it's become Linktext property and is treated as a string rather than .net server side code. Can someone suggest me the solution?

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: Yes, it's got resolved as per suggestion given by archit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following code snippet in your DWT

```
<h2>
    <a tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@">@@HTMLDecode(Component.Fields.Name)@@</a>;
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems another issue with your dwt, @@Component.Fields.Name@@ should have been resolved to component name after publishing.

When page is publish this anchor tag will be converted to

```
<tag attr2="" atr1="" >
```

and all special characters like "<" are encoded, so server code will never execute, just print on the page

You can use C# fragment/tbb

- in c# code do the encoding, push in package.
- get the value from package and include wherever required.